# Split string base on a list of words

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-wrangling

Imagine i have a column:

[image]

Is there and easy way using tidyverse to split the column into two columns base on a list of patterns?

For example the list would contain c(ATOM, SOL, BUSD, UNI) and base on this list the column would be split like this

[image]

thanks

PS: I'm only able to do this in a very convoluted way searching and removing patterns so i'm looking an easier solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one string of patterns and use `str_extract_all` to extract the relevant keywords.

Using @www's data :

```
library(stringr)
target_string <- c("ATOM", "SOL", "UNI", "BUSD", "BTC")
do.call(rbind, str_extract_all(dat$Text, str_c(target_string, collapse = '|')))

#       [,1]   [,2]  
#[1,] "ATOM" "BUSD"
#[2,] "SOL"  "BTC" 
#[3,] "SOL"  "BUSD"
#[4,] "SOL"  "BUSD"
#[5,] "UNI"  "BUSD"
```

Or similar base R way :

```
do.call(rbind, regmatches(dat$Text, gregexpr(paste0(target_string, collapse = '|'), dat$Text)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one idea. We can construct the right regular expression call, and then use `extract` to split the data. In this example, I assume the scenario is you need to find the first column with the strings in `target_string`, while keep everything to the second string.

```
library(tidyverse)

target_string <- c("ATOM", "SOL", "UNI")
target_regex <- paste0("(", paste0(paste0("^", target_string), collapse = "|"), ")(.*)")

dat2 <- dat %>%
  extract(Text, into = c("Col1", "Col2"), regex = target_regex)
dat2
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   Col1  Col2 
#   <chr> <chr>
# 1 ATOM  BUSD 
# 2 SOL   BTC  
# 3 SOL   BUSD 
# 4 SOL   BUSD 
# 5 UNI   BUSD
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- tribble(
  ~Text,
  "ATOMBUSD",
  "SOLBTC",
  "SOLBUSD",
  "SOLBUSD",
  "UNIBUSD"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
    rx <- "^(ATOM|SOL|BUSH|UNI)(.*)$"
    d %>% cbind( str_match( .$Pair, rx )[,-1] )
```

`tidyr::separate` with a zero-width regular expression *might* have worked, but variable-width zero-width patterns arent supported. For some time. Which really is a shame.